# Displaying an applet in tapestry5?

Tags: tapestry, applet

I am getting a strange error when trying to display an applet on a page in my tapestry application. The error says that there is an incompatible magic value.
Is there a certain way to display applets in tapestry?
Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Tapestry at all.

AFAIK, there are two scenarios that can cause this:

- The URL to the JAR file is wrong and results in a 404 error. (See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390733/incompatible-magic-value-1008813135).)
- You're running the Applet with an earlier version of Java than you compiled it for (say 1.4 with a 1.5 class file).

Comment: The only reason I thought it was to do with Tapestry is that I can display the applet perfectly outside of tapestry but when I try display it in Tapestry I get the error!