# Not able to display stock market ticker in HTML

Tags: java

I wanted to generate a live ticker of BSE on my java application.
Now i have this applet code which is supposed to display the ticker/stock prices in an HTMl page.

```
<applet code="bse_ticker.class" width="95%" codebase="http://www.bseindia.com/applet/ticker" height="40" archive="mainticker_finals.jar"></p>
<div class="style8">
<param value="HTTP://www.bseindia.com:5000/price_finder/stockreach.asp?scripcd=" name="url"/>
<param value="#0000FF" name="nullarrowcolor"/>
<param value="_blank" name="window"/>
<param value="#8C8C8C" name="WATERCOLOR"/>
<param value="#000000" name="fgcolor"/>
<param value="#ffffff" name="bgcolor"/>
<param value="#00FF00" name="uparrowcolor"/>
<param value="#0671B0" name="fgcolor1"/>
<param value="0" name="default_ticker"/>
<param value="#FF0000" name="downarrowcolor"/>
<param value="21600000" name="thread_sleeptime"/>
<param value="applet" name="INDEXOF"/>
<param value="TickerData_final.asp" name="dataurl"/>
                </div>
<p></applet><br />
```

However, when i try to open my HTML page which has this code embedded in it, I get Error saying:

> www.java-ticker.net
>
> ```
> Site: investgeeta.com
> Date: 09-17-2005
> ```
>
> ============================================== Loaded image:
>   http://www.investgeeta.com/include/ticker/img/separator.gif
>   Loaded image:
>   http://www.investgeeta.com/include/ticker/img/up4.gif
>   Loaded image:
>   http://www.investgeeta.com/include/ticker/img/stay4.gif
>   Loaded image:
>   http://www.investgeeta.com/include/ticker/img/down4.gif
>   java.lang.ClassFormatError:
>   Incompatible magic value 1013478509 in
>   class file bse_ticker     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Exception: java.lang.ClassFormatError:
>   Incompatible magic value 1013478509 in
>   class file bse_ticker

What is this supposed to mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Incompatible magic value 1008813135](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390733/incompatible-magic-value-1008813135)

Answer (score 2):

The number 1013478509 in hex is 0x3C68746D. Break that apart and you get

```
0x3C = <
0x68 = h
0x74 = t
0x6D = m

<htm
```

Or what looks like the beginning of an HTML document.

It looks like the webserver is serving up some HTML instead of the Java classes.

Try visiting the URL for the applet itself and see what it looks like (and be sure to look at the HTTP headers too).

Comment: http://www.bseindia.com/applet/ticker/bse_ticker.class -> 404 message in a web page (the acid test of your theory).

Comment: does it mean that the ticker is no longer in the server?

Comment: @sunandan It means that the webserver (and by extension, your local JVM/web browser) can't find your Java applet

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue with trying to run a Jar that was created with a newer version of Java than they JVM you are trying to execute the code with.

Do you have multiple versions of bse_ticker? What version was it inteded to run with?