# GRAILS Incompatible magic value 0

Tags: grails

Any idea on what this means and how I might start to resolve?

Incompatible magic value 0 in class file _GrailsPackage_groovy

I'm on a Windows 7 64x box, with JDK 1.6.0_23.

Comment: you might find some clues here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390733/incompatible-magic-value-1008813135

Answer (score 0):

Usually to do with incompatible Java class versions (e.g. class was compiled with 1.5 and run with 1.6), although you usually get a specific number with the magic value instead of 0.

Check you have no other versions of Java around, and maybe do a grails clean and/or delete everything in your /.grails folder (will mean it'll have to download plugins etc again).

Comment: delete everything in your /.grails folder (will mean it'll have to download plugins etc again).

Answer (score 0):

What I think happened is I had created my plugin a while ago for testing purposes, deleted it, and then recreated it recently. I'm guessing something in my  .grails directory in my users folder was messed up.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered a similar issue with a JSP file. If this file is a JSP, delete the class file. It will get re-compiled the next time someone touches the file, and the error should vanish.