# Putting Java applet onto server

Tags: java, javascript, applet

My applet that connects JS/Java with LiveConnect worked from localhost but when transferring to server I get this error in java applet console. Do I have to do something before I transfer these files?

> java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 1008821359 in class file PrintJob/Print_Runner at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Exception: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 1008821359 in class file PrintJob/Print_Runner

Comment: Might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390733/incompatible-magic-value-1008813135

Answer (score 0):

That means the class files didn't transfer properly. If you're using an FTP server make sure you have the binary option enabled.