# Serializing java.lang.class

Tags: java, reflection, classloader, binary-serialization

I have a problem persisting the Class object in the DB.

I tried to convert the object into a byte array using object `ObjectArrayOutputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream` as shown below and persisted it the byte array:

```
Class klazz = getClassForClassDef();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject(klazz);
baos.toByteArray();
```

But I get an error shown below:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 2901213189 in class file
```

I think that the way byte array was constructed has the problem. But I don't know how to create a correct `.class` equivalent of the class object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are really trying to **store the `Class` itself**:

You can read more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2390763/1001027

If you are trying to **store an Object**:

You are using the `Class` as parameter for the `writeObject` method. Instead of this you should use the instance you have.

---

```
// write the class
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject(objectToSerialize);

// this you need to store
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

// read it again (just a test)
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
Object restored = new ObjectInputStream(bais).readObject();

// write what came from the deserialization
System.out.println(restored);
```

In the sample, the variable `objectToSerialize` will hold the object to store.

---

Are you sure you want really store java serialized objects into your database? There are a few alternatives to that. You could create a formal model using an ORM framework such as Hibernate.

If you think this would be too dynamic, you could use XML serialization such as XStream or even JSON serialization, this would be good because they are readable formats, meaning you can see what is really stored, avoiding the need to deserialize it with a Java application just to check the state.

Comment: Well. Actually my problem is not to store all java serialized objects. But I need to load classes stored in a DB at runtime. I have created a model to represent the metadata of a simple class. With little coding I managed to create the Class object from the model by using the metadata. But I am not able to store the class object and retrieve to load class at runtime using reflections.

Comment: Ok, meaning you need to perform the two lines of code I posted on the sample below the commente `// read it again (just a test)` where data would be the `byte[]` retrieved from your database field

Comment: The error is gone now. But I am nowhere near my target. This time I am getting a ClassNotFoundException. When it tries to load the persisted Class object, it is not able to find the .class equivalent of it. Let me try more to get that loaded, may be using some classloader tricks..

Answer (score 1):

To serialise an object you have to write into the stream the object itself rather than it's class. Additionally, the object instance must implement the `Serializable` interface and all its internal fields should be either serializable or transient.

In your code, instead of `oos.writeObject(klazz);` you should write `oos.writeObject(obj);`, providing `obj` is the object instance you want to save.

However, if you are trying to store a Java object into a DB (we are talking about a relational DB, aren't we?) I would map the object to a table, storing each of its attributes as values for the columns. That way you would be able to perform searches and joins using SQL and the values for the columns, you can't index binary fields though.

Comment: Right. But in my case one of the fields is the to store the class and load it at runtime from the field.

Comment: and why would you want to store the class itself? wouldn't it be better to store the class name and then load the class with `Class.forName(...)`?

Answer (score 1):

A `.class` file is **not a serialized Class object**. It is something completely different, and you will not be able to produce it with any simple Java code. However, why would you want to? You already have that `.class` file on disk, that's how your Java program got to know about the class. Why don't you just copy that `.class` file? It will only be an issue of finding where it comes from (what JAR).

Comment: Yes. I used that phrase just to imply that I have to load the class from DB field just as we do from a .class file.