# SBT assembly output 0xEFBFBD instead of 0xCAFEBABE in class file

Tags: java, scala, utf-8, sbt, sbt-assembly

| Tools | Version |
| --- | --- |
| OS | Win10 |
| JavaJDK | 11 |
| Scala | 2.13.5 |
| SBT | 1.3.13 |
| Assembly | 2.1.0 |

[The repository of sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly)

1. The Error message.

I run `assembly` in sbt shell and it prints [success].

Then I try to run the output *.jar* with `java -jar MyProject.jar` in cmd, and get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 4022320623 in class file Main
```

The same error message as this one: [Java Incompatible magic value 4022320623](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111065/java-incompatible-magic-value-4022320623)

But all my work are done locally without any upload or download operation.

2. The header of the class files.

I decompression the *.jar* package and find that all *.class* files are started with `0xEFBFBD EFBFBD`, which means the character cannot be recognized by `UTF-8`.

I've run `sbt package` before, in that case, every java class file is started with `0xCAFE BABE`.

I compared these two class files in binary form. Most of them are the same, but the one generated by assembly command has several `0xEFBFBD` in it.

3. What I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to assembly a large project with multiple modules to one *.jar* file.

- The whole project is encoded in `UTF-8` =>
  IDEA: Global / Project Encoding: `UTF-8`
- SBT has VM option: `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`
- build.sbt has line: `javaOptions ++= Seq("-encoding", "UTF-8")`

I tried everything I can to make sure all the files are encoded & decoded in `UTF-8`.

4. Other versions of assembly.

I also tried sbt-assembly releases *2.1.1* and *2.0.0*, and got the same results.

I need to customize the Merge Strategy which is supported after *2.0.0*, so I didn't try more versions.

I can't show any code here since I don't have right to do so. But if you need more information about this issue please let me know.

Comment: According to the [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12111542/12083015) to the link that you gave, the problem was when writing the file, not when downloading the file. Maybe you can check it too.

Comment: `CAFEBABE` is (hexadecimal) Java class file [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) (so called *magic number*) while `EFBFBD` are `UTF-8` bytes for [Replacement Character](https://symbl.cc/en/FFFD/) and `4022320623` is decimal representation for `0xEFBFBDEF` (== 4 leading bytes in **EFBFBDEF**BFBD).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say without `libraryDependencies` and `assemblyMergeStrategy` of your `build.sbt` and without a specific class of assembly jar that is not valid.

I suspect that `MergeStrategy.concat` or `MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines` was incorrectly applied to some `.class` files and this leads to not valid class files. `MergeStrategy.concat / filterDistinctLines` are for config files, `.properties` files, service files (i.e. files with names `com.example.SomeInterface` and contents `com.example.impl.SomeImplementation`) etc., not for `.class` files.

You can temporarily change `assemblyMergeStrategy` to

```
assembly / assemblyMergeStrategy := {
  case _ => MergeStrategy.singleOrError
}
```

to see all the duplicates, or to

```
ThisBuild / assemblyMergeStrategy := {
  case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith ".class" => MergeStrategy.singleOrError
  case x =>
    val standardStrategy = (ThisBuild / assemblyMergeStrategy).value
    standardStrategy(x)
}
```

to see all the `.class` duplicates. You should see among them the class files that become not valid upon `MergeStrategy.concat/filterDistinctLines`.

Sbt 1.3.13 is quite old, current is 1.8.2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll check the merge strategy.

Comment: Thank you very much, the reason is that I mistakenly merge the class files.

Comment: @Bean Great! Congrats.