# Could not find the main class: SortAlgorithms

Tags: java, linux, bash, boinc

I have this Java class:

```
public class SortAlgorithms {
public static void main(String... args) {

        String out = "";
        int vec1[] = readFile(args[0]);

        out = out + write(vec1);
        out = out + "=== INSERTION SORT ===\n";
        insertionSort(vec1, vec1.length);
        out = out + write(vec1) + "\n";
...
}
...
}
```

And I deploy it on other machine at my Boinc platform. There is a bash script to run this class:

```
#!/bin/sh

export JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_34/"
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}

java SortAlgorithms 10 "output.txt" > saida.txt
```

And I receive this error:

```
<stderr_txt>
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 1014198118 in class file SortAlgorithms
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: SortAlgorithms.  Program will exit.

</stderr_txt>
```

Does anyone know what is happening?
Thnaks in advance.
Felipe

Comment: related/dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390733/incompatible-magic-value-1008813135

Comment: I am not using applets. I don't have cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class file was not copied properly. It starts with string '<sof' which is definitely not a java bytecode start.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Java API:

> file is malformed or otherwise cannot be interpreted as a class file.

I believe that you need to compile your Java file on the machine which will be running the code.

Answer (score 0):

While both maxkar and user1773630's answers seem right, it does sound like a .class file wasn't transferred properly.  Compare checksums, or make a .jar?

If you've got jdk's with differing major versions installed, there can be class compatibility issues as well, which can cause a similar error.