# Java jar error: Incompatible magic value

Tags: java, jar, applet

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value
>   1347093252 in class file

Though the question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390733/incompatible-magic-value-1008813135?rq=1), error continues after following the best answer. (i.e. after clearing the java cache from *java control panal* and deleting all temporary files.)

Comment: Most likely problem is that your jar is corrupted!

Comment: Solved, need to build again.