# Java Incompatible magic value 1694957703

Tags: java, classformaterror

I've freshly built the java program 3 different times in eclipse and they run fine on the windows machine. I get the following error when I run them on the linux box (I've tried winscp and ftp).

> Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 1694957703 in class file sun/security/ssl/SSLContextImpl$TLSContext

The program runs fine until I try to have it write and upload a xml file. It doesn't seem to have any problems writing the file.

Comment: Can you give us more details about your code and where exactly do you get this exception?

Comment: This isn't completely a duplicate.  This question does not reference Applets, but this other one does:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390733/incompatible-magic-value-1008813135